# Refactoring triggers into batches

Tags: trigger, batch

Is there any good practices on how to refactor Apex triggers into batch processes?

I've been given quite a large trigger that is exceeding CPU limits due to large processing size. The aim is to move this logic into batch classes. The biggest problem (besides being quite a big problem itself) is that current helpers using trigger.oldMap, mostly to compare the changed values. Wondering what would be a way to replicate this in batch class.

**Edit**: One reasonable idea I heard was marking record for further processing in batch. It's sort of decouples the entry criteria from actual processing.

Comment: Are you planning to schedule batches on a predefined duration or execute batch every time trigger is executing?

Comment: I doubt there would be any benefit to doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to follow every best practice that goes with Batch Process. There are no as such specific "Trigger to Batch Class conversion" best practices, however you should be careful about

1. Make sure you execute batch process only when there are huge amount of records in Trigger, not every time a record is inserted or updated.
2. Keep an eye on number of batches scheduled currently. Flex queue supports upto 100 of them.

Regarding Trigger.oldMap, just simply pass these value to a Map variable in the batch class and use them in the method.

**Note :** If you think doubling the execution time can solve the problem, you can also process some data in Future methods, instead of moving to Batch class. This will help to maintain your existing solution.

Comment: The reason I am asking for best practices is that the model is not new and is applied in other fields/systems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the heaviest part of your trigger to a future method or Queueable method. Avoid using Batchable in trigger calls, because they're fairly limited system-wide. You can use profiling to determine which part(s) you should move. Those that recalculate a ton of data, send emails, or update related records would be the best candidates. Asynchronous code can't properly fire validation errors and so on, and since they may fail for other reasons, should be used sparingly.

Comment: Already tried @future methods, they were causing record lock issues.

Comment: @dzh, in addition to sfdcfox suggestion - consider Appleman's Advanced Apex 3rd edition pattern on how to superscale asynchronous processing using queuable methods

Comment: @crop1645 Queueable Apex looks interesting, might be an actually better solution. Can it be invoked from triggers? Thanks!

Comment: @dzh, I 2nd crop's recommendation on Appleman's Advanded Apex 3rd Edition Patterns. Am doing an implementation right now using that pattern with queueables and yes, they can be invoked from triggers in the same way a batch class can.

Comment: @dzh Yes, queueable can be called any time a batch can be, but without the system wide limit of 100 queued jobs. There is a limit to how many jobs you can you add per transaction, of course, but it's far more generous than batches.